# Get/Change value of widget controls dynamically in Elementor

Tags: jquery, wordpress, widget, controls, elementor

I am developing a plugin for the elementor editor , and I am stuck with this problem that I need help resolving,
I need to get the Values of the controls on the side , like for example getting the value of “Info” control (custom contorl that i have made) , by clicking the “Generate Button “ ,
How to connect the “GenerateEvent” the Generate Button in the right scope to get the values from the widget panel.

My widget plugin looks like this :

[image: Plugin Widget]

Trying to attach an hook on Generate Event with code, and trying to take the Order info to a defiend variable like this :

```
jQuery( window ).on( 'elementor/frontend/init', () => {
    elementor.channels.editor.on('GenerateEvent', () => {
        let info = window.jQuery("[data-setting='Info']").val();
        console.log( Info );
        let tash = window.jQuery("[data-setting='tash']")[0].value;
        console.log(info);
        let tashType = jQuery("[data-setting='tashType']")[0].value;
        let FixTash = jQuery("[data-setting='tashType']")[0].value;
        let sendemail = jQuery("[data-setting='sendemail']")[0].value;
        let PageLang = jQuery("[data-setting='PageLang']")[0].value;
        let Coin = jQuery("[data-setting='Coin']")[0].value;
        let Postpone = jQuery("[data-setting='Postpone']")[0].value;
        let J5 = jQuery("[data-setting='J5']")[0].value;


});
```

});

But the problem its not defiend on the same scope … and i get this error , also when i write the command in the console i actually getting the info (because the scope is the right scope)

**What is the right scope to access variables in my code or in other words what is the code that i need to wrote or some hook that i need to attach , so i can retrieve the Info from the elementor widget editor ?**

[image: Console]